# Subplots with same height in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have something like

```
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(y1)
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(y2)
subplot(2,2,[2 4])
plot(y3)
```

The last plot plotting `y3` does not get the same height as the plots `y1 + y2`. How can I fix this?

Hugh Nolan is right. There shouldn't be any problem in general. However, boxplots seem to shrink automatically after being plotted.

How can I get the boxplot to have the same height as the side-by-side subplots?

Answer (score 1):

The `ylim` function allows you to get and set the limits of the y axis, so you could do:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(y1)
yl1=ylim;
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(y2)
ylim(yl1);
subplot(2,2,[2 4])
plot(y3)
ylim(yl1);
```

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question. Your code works for me. What version of Matlab are you using? What does your figure look like? What exactly is your code? Since what you have posted works, it is probably another part of the code which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify the position, width and height of each subplot by using `subplot('Position',[left bottom width height])` instead of the habitual `subplot` command. For more info see the Mathworks [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html).

Comment: `left` and `bottom` are the distance from the bottom left corner of the figure where you want the subplot to appear. If you want to get the values of the other subplot, you can call it with an handle and then use the `get` function. Something like: `sp1 = subplot(2,2,1);` and then `[left bottom width height] = get(sp1,'Position');`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try axes/axis function? That sets the xlim and ylim of the graph.